# Scala assign value in if else statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Pretty new to scala.

I have an if else statement which based on a condition, assigns value to a variable.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel, PipelineStage}
modelType = "rf" 

def train(trainingData: DataFrame): PipelineModel = {

        val xgb = new XGBoostClassifier()
          .setLabelCol("label")
          .setFeaturesCol("features")
          .setObjective("binary:logistic")
          .setEvalMetric("auc")  

        val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
          .setLabelCol("label")
          .setFeaturesCol("features")
          .setImpurity("gini")

         if (modelType == "rf") {
             val pipeline = new Pipeline()
              .setStages(Array[PipelineStage](rf))
             } else if (modelType == "xgb") {
            val pipeline = new Pipeline()
              .setStages(Array[PipelineStage](rf))
             }


        pipeline.fit(trainingData)
        }
```

But i am seeing this error: `pipeline not found`. Does this mean the pipeline variable is not assigned? How can i rewrite this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the if to the variable

```
  val xgb = new XGBoostClassifier()
              .setLabelCol("label")
              .setFeaturesCol("features")
              .setObjective("binary:logistic")
              .setEvalMetric("auc")  

            val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
              .setLabelCol("label")
              .setFeaturesCol("features")
              .setImpurity("gini")

           val pipeline =  if (modelType == "rf") {
                  new Pipeline()
                  .setStages(Array[PipelineStage](rf))
                 } else if (modelType == "xgb") {
                new Pipeline()
                  .setStages(Array[PipelineStage](rf))
                 }
                  }

            pipeline.fit(trainingData)
            }
```

Comment: To elaborate, in general, a `val` defined in a block (including the then or else clause of an `if`) is only visible until the end of that block.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Thank you for the explanation. I know my answer was lacking a explanation. I had this same problem as OP and spent more time than I would like to admit looking for an answer. I never made an attempt to research more than just the needed syntax so thank you!

Comment: To further clarify the reason why this works, when any closure is resolved, it resolves to the value of the last line. In this case, the last line is the `new Pipeline`.